# Type 'Any' has no subscript members, indexPath

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I am trying to get info from a mysql database and I have the following code. I have tried to use the edits found on other pages but I am new to programming and can not figure out what I have done wrong.

```
    func get(){
    let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.157.134/Getdepartment.php")
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
    values = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSArray
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return values.count;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! SpecialCell
    let maindata = values[indexPath.row]
    cell.username.text = maindata["Username"] as? String
    cell.password.text = maindata["Password"] as? String
    cell.num.text = maindata["FavoriteNumber"] as? String
    cell.info.text = maindata["Info"] as? String
    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned very very often Foundation `NSArray` provides no type information so it doesn't help the Swift compiler at all.

In Swift 3 the compiler **must** know the type of all subscripted objects otherwise you get errors.

To solve the problem first of all declare your data source array as Swift `Array` containing Swift `Dictionary`. That makes the compiler – and eventually you – happy.

```
var values = [[String:Any]]()
```

If all dictionary values are strings you can even declare `values` as `[[String:String]]`

Secondly cast the deserialization line to the same type:

```
values = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [[String:Any]]
```

PS: `mutableContainers` is useless in Swift, pass empty `options`

Side-note:

Even in the local network do not load data from a remote URL synchronously via `Data(contentsOf:`